# Running a bash script on double click does not have all environment variables

Tags: bash, shell-script, nautilus

I am running `Debian`. I have a `jar` file that I need to execute. A wrapper `bash` script does a `java -jar MyProg.jar`. The `jar` also calls some `C` code for which `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` needs to be set.

I have set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in the current user's (let's say Sriram)'s bashrc like so:
`export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=myLibLocation`.

Everything works as expected when running the above script from the command line. However, when I run the same bash file by double-clicking on it, `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` is not set. Here is a sample `bash` script I wrote:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo `whoami`;
echo "PATH = ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"
```

It runs as expected from the command line but not when I run it by double-clicking. The output in that case is:

```
Sriram
PATH =
```

[This](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/170156/bash-scripts-ran-from-from-gnome-nautilus-dont-have-enviroment-variables?newreg=43c4572df7e04bceaf3928314bbb2fd8) question is exactly the same as this. I have tried to implement all the suggestions there but have not had success.

Update:

What I tried from the answer to the question I linked to:
1. Created a file `~/.xsessionrc`. It did not exist on my system.
2. Set `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` in the above script.

Restarted a new shell. Re-ran the above script. No changes were observed.

Any help is most welcome.

Comment: Can you show/explain what you have implemented from the similar question/answer because it should have worked.

Comment: @XTian: Added more information.

Comment: Just a detail but... why would you do ``echo `whoami`;`` instead of just `whoami`?

Comment: @Celada: It **might** echo "whoami" rather than the currently signed in user name. I wanted the result of that command echoed to see what user is executing the script (Nautilus or me).

Comment: Environment variables go into `.profile`, not `.bashrc`. The problem you're observing is the main reason not to define environment variables in `.bashrc`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (you're missing a **'#!'** and it's also usually better to set program-specific environment in that program's wrapper script rather than ~/.bashrc to not potentially affect other programs):

```
#!/bin/bash
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=myLibLocation
echo `whoami`;
echo "PATH = ${LD_LIBRARY_PATH}"
```

Comment: Thanks, but in the script these have been added. That must have been a typo.

Comment: Exporting LD_LIBRARY_PATH works as you suggest. I am looking for a more permanent solution like appending that path to the bashrc etc.