# How to recognize binaries installed in `~/bin`?

Tags: bash, debian, binary

I am trying to execute some binaries manually installed in a `bin` directory in my `$HOME` (normal user).

Files are present in `/home/user/bin` and have exec permission:

```
$ ls -la ~/bin/
total 120
drwxr-xr-x  2 my_user my_user  4096 déc.   8 12:04 .
drwxr-xr-x 94 my_user my_user  4096 déc.   8 12:23 ..
-rwxr-xr-x  1 my_user my_user  4843 déc.   8 12:04 dplx
-rwxr-xr-x  1 my_user my_user  6515 déc.   8 12:04 dprint
-rwxr-xr-x  1 my_user my_user  2123 déc.   8 12:04 dprintm
-rwxr-xr-x  1 my_user my_user 15494 déc.   8 12:04 duplex
-rwxr-xr-x  1 my_user my_user  6501 déc.   8 12:04 kmprb
-rwxr-xr-x  1 my_user my_user 11069 déc.   8 12:04 kmprb_one
-rwxr-xr-x  1 my_user my_user  5543 déc.   8 12:04 krmpq
-rwxr-xr-x  1 my_user my_user  8267 déc.   8 12:04 mpr
-rwxr-xr-x  1 my_user my_user 25452 déc.   8 12:04 mprb
-rwxr-xr-x  1 my_user my_user  2953 déc.   8 12:04 pqnext
-rwxr-xr-x  1 my_user my_user   896 déc.   8 12:04 rmpq
```

And `~/.profile` contains the call for `~/bin` (it's the default on debian).

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

However, binaries are not recognized after a reboot:

```
$ duplex
bash: duplex : commande introuvable
```

I also tried `source .bashrc` and `source .profile`. The second one works but just for the terminal (if I close it and reopen a new one, the command isn't recognize anymore).

How could I permanently install these binaries?

Comment: "~/.profile: executed by the command interpreter for login shells.
# This file is not read by bash(1), if ~/.bash_profile or ~/.bash_login
# exists." It begs the question, do you have a .bash_profile or .bash_login file?

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/170156/19575

At least the problem is the same.

Answer (score 0):

The file(s) `profile` are meant to be read by all shells on start for **login** shells. Either the system wide `/etc/profile` (and /etc/profile.d) or the user added file `~/.profile`.

For interactive, non-login shells, (most of the shells) you should use the file(s) `.bashrc`.

Just move the code:

```
# set PATH so it includes user's private bin if it exists
if [ -d "$HOME/bin" ] ; then
    PATH="$HOME/bin:$PATH"
fi
```

from `~/.profile` to `~/.bashrc`.

Or, alternative (I really do not recommend that) source `~/.profile` in `~/.bashrc`.

To better understand the way the files are used, please [look at this image](http://www.solipsys.co.uk/new/BashInitialisationFiles.html).