# Unable to add directory to PATH environment on Linux/ParrotSec

Tags: linux, bash, parrotsec

After downloading the [Intellij IDEA programming software](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/), the Installation document suggests that I add it to the PATH Environment, yet I am unable to do so using the "export" command as many of the forums suggest.

I run the command as so:

```
sudo export PATH=/home/myusername/Programming/idea-IC-222.4167.29/bin:$PATH
```

Yet am met with this error message:

```
sudo: export: command not found
```

I have tried finding solutions to this and am struggling. I've also tried finding guides on how to install the export function onto my system but have had no luck.

I'm using ParrotOS Security Edition 5.0 Electro Ara.

Any suggestions/help would be much appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `sudo` doesn't help you here. The `export` statement changes the environment of the currently running process (only). The same statement without the `sudo` in front will probably work in your current shell (where you typed the export statement), but not in any other window or even user session.

```
export PATH=/home/myusername/Programming/idea-IC-222.4167.29/bin:$PATH
command -v idea.sh # this should print /home/myusername/Programming/idea-IC-222.4167.29/bin/idea.sh
idea.sh            # this should start IntelliJ
```

In order to permanently change the `PATH` variable for your user, theere are many possibilities. I explored a little once in [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/170161/19575)

Comment: This worked, thank you! As a novice with Linux I got so used to running every command with sudo I never considered this. Thanks for solving my problem and helping me deepen my understanding at the same time 